# Custom login rules in ASP.NET Identity are validated, but browser still redirects to Home

Tags: c#, authentication, redirect, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

In ASP.NET MVC5 I'm using ASP.NET Identity and I had to implement some custom login rules in addition to `PasswordSignInAsync` by adding a `PasswordSignInAsync` overload to `ApplicationSignInManager` and an additional property to store a status:

```
public class ApplicationSignInManager : SignInManager<ApplicationUser, string>
{
    public EnumCompanyStatus CompanyStatus { get; private set; }

    public ApplicationSignInManager(ApplicationUserManager userManager, IAuthenticationManager authenticationManager) : base(userManager, authenticationManager)
    {
        CompanyStatus = EnumCompanyStatus.Active;
    }

    // Standard scaffolding omitted

    public async Task<SignInStatus> PasswordSignInAsync(string userName, string password, bool isPersistent, bool shouldLockout, Func<string, EnumCompanyStatus> getCompanyStatus)
    {
        SignInStatus signInStatus = await base.PasswordSignInAsync(userName, password, isPersistent, shouldLockout);

        if (signInStatus == SignInStatus.Success)
        {
            CompanyStatus = getCompanyStatus(userName);

            if (CompanyStatus != EnumCompanyStatus.Active)
                signInStatus = SignInStatus.Failure;
        }

        return signInStatus;
    }
}
```

And this is my Login method in `AccountController`:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View(model);
        }

        var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, false, GetCompanyStatus);

        switch (result)
        {
            case SignInStatus.Success:
                return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
            case SignInStatus.LockedOut:
                return View("Lockout");
            case SignInStatus.RequiresVerification:
                return RedirectToAction("SendCode", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = model.RememberMe });
            case SignInStatus.Failure:
            default:
                if (SignInManager.CompanyStatus == EnumCompanyStatus.Disabled)
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", "User disabled.");
                else if (SignInManager.CompanyStatus == EnumCompanyStatus.Frozen)
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", "Please contact our support.");
                else
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid login attempt.");
                return View(model);
        }
    }
```

My problem lies in the `default` case in the `switch/case` statement. Whenever `SignInManager.CompanyStatus` is `Disabled` or `Frozen`, this corresponding code will be reached correctly, however, **most of the times** the user will still be  redirected to the home page instead of having the aplication just printing my error messages. It has worked a couple of times, but my breakpoints were in the way. Should execution reach the last condition, a traditional login failed attempt, it works perfectly (the error message is displayed in the Login page and no redirections take place), but .NET doesn't seem too happy with my messing around with `signInStatus`. What am I missing here? I can only imagine there is another property getting in my way, but I tackled web development in years and I could really use some help right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After fumbling around a bit more, I figured that yes, PasswordSignInAsync was indeed changing an internal status which validated my request regardless of what I did afterwards. So I just swapped the order of custom validation and base method call:

```
    public async Task<SignInStatus> PasswordSignInAsync(string userName, string password, bool isPersistent, bool shouldLockout, Func<string, EnumCompanyStatus> getCompanyStatus)
    {
        CompanyStatus = getCompanyStatus(userName);

        if (CompanyStatus != EnumCompanyStatus.Active)
            return SignInStatus.Failure;

        return await base.PasswordSignInAsync(userName, password, isPersistent, shouldLockout);
    }
```